# Understanding "this" in JQuery UI Widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, this

Normally if I want to create a click event in JQuery I use the following syntax:

`$("#test").on("click", function() { console.log($(this)); });`

Here I can easily refer to the clicked element using the `this` keyword.

However in JQuery UI Widgets, it seems the format they want is:

```
this._on( $("li", this.list), {
      dblclick: function() { 
        console.log$(this);
      }
});
```

The problem is, that JQuery UI uses `this` for the widget, and I'm unable to refer to the `this` that was clicked. Is there a special syntax I need?

The problem with using the normal JQuery method is that I can't my widget variables inside of it due to the `this` then referring to what was clicked.

Do I need to create a temporary placeholder variable to make this work (like `var temp = this.myVar`), or is there another workaround?

Comment: could you post more code, what is this in your case? specially the function ond options declaration for your widget would be nice

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I wrote it out as best I knew how. Nomad101 understood and answered the question perfectly. I merely wanted to understand how to reach the varying scopes of nested elements/listeners.

Comment: so you want to know the differences between this._on object, this.list and this inside the functions scope?

Comment: I wanted to know how to refer to `this` (the event target) inside of an event without referring to the widget.

Comment: dblclick:function(e) {console.log(e.target)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the this keyword in the ui plugin is the element that the ui plugin is currently operating on. I would take a look on how to make a plugin here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

That should give you the required information. However you can think of the ui-plugin code as a single iteration of the `.each()` method and the `this` keyword is the currently searched element in the list that you would get from say this `$("p.findMe")`. So in essence the `this` keyword is used so that another search of the DOM tree is not necessary.

The click function has some arguments that you can pass, such as the target element. take a look at this:
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Now specifically you will want to focus on the event object mentioned in the function overloads. By using `function(event){}` instead of `function()` in your `dblclick` you can use it to get the target element and all other information dealing with the event like its click location and parent elements.

Comment: Thank you. This is all great information. So how would I have access to a "this" contained inside of a listener inside of the widget?

Comment: Thank you. `event.target` is what I needed.